# Add parameter in the exported filename in SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have an SSRS report which I am building using MS Report Builder. When I export the report as PDF or Excel, the file is downloaded with the default report name. Can I save using the file with one of the parameters in the report as filename?
For example, say I am making a report of sales data for a company, one of the parameters is `product_name`, can I save the exported file as `product_name_mm_dd_yyy.pdf` or `product_name_mm_dd_yyy.csv`

I have seen a few answers with changing the default name, but have not seen any implementation using parameter within the report

Comment: If you're downloading the report, then it's up to what ever is downloading said file to choose the name of it.

Comment: Is it possible to download it automatically with the name whenever the user tries to export file, with the filename as the parameter value in the report? @Larnu

Comment: Just get the user to type the name in the "save as" dialogue... That's not a hardship on the user.

Comment: @Larnu I know that would be an easy way to go, but in my case, I do not want the user to make any mistake with entering an incorrect name, as these reports go to a shared drive, then again some information is queried back from these reports after exporting. Is there a way to achieve a solution to this?

Comment: If you don't want to introduce user errors, don't give the task to a user. Use a scheduled report subscription with data derived report settings (which can be achieved with standard edition, if you search).